# Eloquent morphOne relationship doesn't limit to one relation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphism

I am having a issue with an Eloquent `morphOne` relationship where it is creating new entries rather than updating the one that already exists.

Basically I have a number of models (for example, let's say `Person` and `Building`) that both need a location, so I have created a `Location` model:

```
class Location extends Eloquent {

    public function locationable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

Then in my other models I have this:

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    // ...

    /**
     * Get the person's location
     * 
     * @return Location
     */
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Location', 'locationable');
    }

    // ...
```

```
class Building extends Eloquent {

    // ...

    /**
     * Get the building's location
     * 
     * @return Location
     */
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('Location', 'locationable');
    }

    // ...
```

When I run the following test code, it creates the location entry fine, but if I repeat it, it creates more entries.

```
$person = Person::first();

$loc = new Location;

$loc->lat = "123";
$loc->lng = "321";

$person->location()->save($loc);
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I would have expected `morphOne` to constrain this to one entry per type, so the last entry in the table below should not exist:

```
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|  locationable_id    |   locationable_type      |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
|  2                  |  Building                |
|  3                  |  Building                |
|  2                  |  Person                  |
|  2                  |  Building                |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: No, you're not doing it wrong. It's just how it works. Polymorphic relations are good for easy stuff, but the further you go, the more bugs you find.

Comment: So do you suggest to avoid them wherever possible? Doesn't make sense for me to do anything else but create a polymorphic relation. 1) Someone suggests doing a simple if else check to see if the `orderable_type` is empty then create, otherwise update, what is your opinion on this? 2) https://i.imgur.com/gPmh1OK.png Opinion on this? Would love to hear it. Thank you man.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I'm late for the party, but this worked for me!

```
# Do we have location already?
if($person->location) {
    return $person->location()->update($location);
}
return $person->location()->create($location);
```

Comment: I usually put this in a method on the model: `saveLocation(Location $location){ ... }` for a nice and easy api

Answer (score 3):

Actually, by calling

```
$loc = new Location;
```

you are, by definition, creating a new location!

Calling

```
$person->location()->save($loc);
```

doesn't help either.

IF you want to *update* a location, you need to find the location, update it's values and then save it. Independently from the parent model:

```
$person = Person::first();

$loc = $person->location;

$loc->lat = "123";
$loc->lng = "321";

$loc->save();
```

Done.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my very current experiences, this solution should be works

Creation or replace old by new Location model instance:

```php
$person = Person::first();

$loc = new Location;

$loc->lat = "123";
$loc->lng = "321";

$loc->save();
$person->location()->associate($loc);
$person->save();
```

Update:

```php
$person = Person::first();

$person->location->lat = "123";
$person->location->lng = "321";

$person->location->save();
$person->save();
```

I spent many days for finding out this solution. Hope they would document it much better officially.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do create or update things on either a hasOne or morphOne related model is to use the "updateOrCreate" function.

In my case, A client can have one address so I do the following and works for me

```
$client->address()->updateOrCreate([], $addressData);
```

The same thing can also be applied in case of hasOne relationship like a user can only have one profile so I do the following.

```
$user->profile()->updateOrCreate([], $data);
```

**User.php**

```
class User {
    /**
     * Get the user profile information associated with the user.
     */
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }
}
```

**Client.php**

```
class Client {
    /**
     * Get all of the client's addresses.
     */
    public function address()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Address', 'addressadder');
    }
}
```