# Calling save() on morphOne() relationship with an existing record creates a new record without removing the old one

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

If you have a Model, let's say a `Post` model, with a `morphOne()` relationship to an `Image` model. The second time you `$post->image()->save()` you now have two entries in the `images` table for the same `Post`. Since it's a one-to-one relationship, it seems like this shouldn't happen. `$post->image` continues to refer to the first one saved.

The `associate()` method doesn't help either. You can only call it on the `Image` with the `morphTo` property - it will update the post ID but still do nothing to affect the first `Image` saved.

Is this a bug? Should I file it on the Laravel Github? Is there some way around this - do I simply have to manually delete the existing one? [Someone else also made a note of this 6 months ago](http://laravel.io/forum/09-04-2014-polymorphic-issue-morphone?page=1#reply-24772), I am surprised there isn't a fix for this by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flaw in my thinking is that Eloquent relationships were somehow a binding contract - they're not. The only real difference between `hasOne` and `hasMany` in this context, as @Jeff pointed out, is that `hasOne` calls `->first()` for you instead of `->get()`. Laravel requires you to actually maintain these relationships.

This means that even if you have a `morphOne` or `hasOne` relationship between `Post` and `Image` (a Post can only have one Image, and the Image can only belong to one Post), you can call `$post->save($image)` until the cows come home and Laravel will happily create unlimited entries in the `images` table that all list the same `Post` as the "parent ID". It doesn't automatically delete or dissociate the previous one. Similarly you can `associate()` unlimited existing Images to a single Post. Calling `$post->image` will only return the first Image associated to it, which makes sense per my first paragraph.

The [first reply on this Laravel issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2114) discusses this:

> the idea appears to be that Laravel should only be editing models from
>   the side of the relationship that the developer is calling

From what I can tell, this means not updating the `images` table to delete or dissociate an existing image when you're updating the `Post` object.

I think my confusion stemmed from trying to translate the idea of a user uploading a new image to the logic of having to create a new Image object in Laravel. In reality I should updateOrCreate the image of the Post with the new image. If it already has an image object, just update it. It doesn't need to be a new Image object. Or if you need to store the existing image for some reason, simply dissociate it with the Post before adding the one one. Since maintaining the one-to-one relationship is not handled for me, this must be done manually if that's the logic my application requires.

Answer (score 3):

> In reality I should updateOrCreate

I think this is the most ideal solution: using the [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOne.html#method_updateOrCreate) function. The first argument is an array of attributes to find an existing model. The second is the attributes you want to update/add. If you don't care about *any* of the attributes getting overwritten (like in a really simple model), passing an empty array for the first argument will simply update the existing relationship if it has one. This is a compact and clean, and could be a one-liner.

```
$attributesIWantToSave = [
    // ...
];
$post->image()->updateOrCreate([], $attributesIWantToSave);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you shouldn't be calling `$post->image()->save()` but rather `$post->image->save()`.  You are calling save on the relation, which is saving a new one. You should be calling save on the actual image object.

Edit: Read Brynn's response for the solution, MorphOne is a fickle beast

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, what I am actually calling is `$post->image()->save($image)`, where $image is an Image object. If I called `$post->image->save($image)` I would be calling the `save()` function of the image, and it requires that $image be an array, which it is not. It's already existing Image object.

Comment: Hmm I guess I don't know how morphOne works, it seems very poorly documented.  Looking at this answer suggests a few fixes, all of which involve checking to see if there is an existing entry and then either creating a new one or updating the existing one based on that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24694761/laravel-eloquent-morphone-relationship-issue

Comment: If `$post->image` exists you could use the getAttributes function to update the image from your new image object eg. `$post->image->update($image->getAttributes());`, otherwise you could save the new one with `$post->image()->save($image);`

Comment: If you're working with an already-existing image, why do you even need `$post`? The relationships already set. Couldn't you just call `$image->save();`?

Comment: @ThomasKim, the issue isn't saving the Image to the Post, the issue is the Post already has an Image, and saving a new one doesn't remove the old one. Apparently I have to `dissociate()` manually to remove the old one, even though it's a `morphOne()` relationship and it doesn't seem like it should be possible to have multiple.

Comment: So you want to remove the old one and then add a new one rather than just update the old one?

Comment: Brynn I think you are right, you'll just have to do it manually.  the MorphOne class basically just extends MorphOneOrMany and then returns `$query->first()` instead of all of the matched relations.  So you can think of MorphOne as MorphMany with an automatic `->first()` on the results. Just a little shortcut that isn't very intuitive.

Comment: @ThomasKim I think that was the missing piece of logic my brain was hiding from me. You're correct, it's going to be much easier to update the existing Image. But if the Post was allowed to select from a gallery of existing Images, that would become a bit muddy - you'd be updating an existing Image record from another already existing Image record, and having to make a backup of the old one I guess?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Did @Jeff's solution not work? I think either `$post->image->update($image->getAttributes());` or `$post->image->save($image->getAttributes());` should work.

Comment: @ThomasKim, that still just creates a new record and does nothing to the existing record. It works, but it doesn't solve the root problem I am having. I think I have a final conclusion of options and I will be writing a more in-depth answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a trait and class.  Use the trait in your model.  You'll need to fit it into your own namespacing scheme.

```
use MorphExactlyOne as Relation;
trait MorphOne{

    public function morphOne($related, $name, $type = null, $id = null, $localKey = null){
        $instance = $this->newRelatedInstance($related);

        [$type, $id] = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $id);

        $table = $instance->getTable();

        $localKey = $localKey ?:$this->getKeyName();

        return new Relation($instance->newQuery(), $this, $table . '.' . $type, $table . '.' . $id, $localKey);
    }
}
```

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne as BaseRelationship;

class MorphExactlyOne extends BaseRelationship{

    public function save(Model $has_morphTo_relationship){
        if($has_morphTo_relationship = parent::save($has_morphTo_relationship)
            and $has_morphTo_relationship->wasRecentlyCreated){

            $type       = $this->morphClass;
            $type_field = explode('.', $this->morphType);
            $type_field = end($type_field);

            $key       = $this->parent->getKey();
            $key_field = explode('.', $this->foreignKey);
            $key_field = end($key_field);

            $builder = get_class($has_morphTo_relationship);
            $builder::where($key_field, $key)
                    ->where($type_field, $type)
                    ->where($has_morphTo_relationship->getKeyName(), '!=', $has_morphTo_relationship->getKey())
                    ->delete();
        }

    return $has_morphTo_relationship;
    }
}
```